# Drop down option incremental values

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, increment

EDIT - Thanks all - I knew it would be simple...couldn't see the wood from the trees!

```
var abc = new Array('Perth','Auckland');

case '1':
    document.getElementById(q15).options.length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        createOption(document.getElementById(q15), abc[i], abc.[i]);
        }
break;
```

I am sure this is easy but I'm having a mental block.

When the above Javascript outputs a drop down with the values from the array, it produces the following:

```
<option value="Perth">Perth</option>
<option value="Auckland">Auckland</option>
```

However, I really need the following:

```
<option value="1">Perth</option>
<option value="2">Auckland</option>
```

Where the `value=` number increments for all the options.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

H.

Comment: Can you please post the code of `createOption`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this call sets the values:

createOption(document.getElementById(q15), abc[i], abc.[i]);

So try changing either the first or second abc[i] to just i.

Comment: Thank you - couldn't see the wood from the trees!  Thanks also to @Joao.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second argument to your `createOption` function is the value of the `value` attribute:

```
createOption(document.getElementById(q15), i + 1, abc[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use i instead of `abc[i]` OR `abc.[i]`